# MVC5 jquery selected row data with hidden fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I would like to get the selected row data using JQuery I am able to get the data for the visible fields but not for the hidden fields. This is my WebGrid binding

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSelected", "Email", FormMethod.Post))
{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "table",
                selectedRowStyle: "selected",
                headerStyle: "header",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alternate",
                htmlAttributes: new { id = "checkableGrid" },
                columns: grid.Columns
                (
                    grid.Column(
                    format: @<text> <input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" id="@item.MessageID" value="@item.MessageID" name="ids" /> </text>,
                    header: ""),
                    grid.Column("From", "From"),
                    grid.Column("Subject", "Subject"),
                    grid.Column("Body",format:@<text> <input type="hidden" id="@item.MessageID" name="IDHidden" value="@item.Body" /></text>),
                    grid.Column("MailDate", format: @<text> <input type="hidden" id="@item.MessageID" name="IDHidden" value="@item.MailDate" /></text>)
               )
             )
    <span id="validationMessage" />
}
```

My javascript code

```
$('#checkableGrid tr').each(function (i, e) {
  $(e).children('tr td:not(:first)').css('cursor', 'pointer');
  $("#checkableGrid tr:nth-child(n) td").each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
`});
            $(e).children('td:not(:first)').click(function () {
})
})
```

So can some one help me I would like to read each column data with hidden fields.

```
<table class="table" id="checkableGrid">
<thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll" value=""></th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Email/GetMails?sort=From&amp;sortdir=ASC">From</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Email/GetMails?sort=Subject&amp;sortdir=ASC">Subject</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
<a href="/Email/GetMails?sort=Body&amp;sortdir=ASC">Body</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
<a href="/Email/GetMails?sort=MailDate&amp;sortdir=ASC">MailDate</a>            </th>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td> <input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" id="3709" value="3709" name="ids"> </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer;">CouponDunia</td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer;">New Year Offers &amp; More: Paytm Upto 222 Cashback, Amazon EOSS Upto70% Off, eBay Top Deals on Electronics &amp; More</td>
            <td style="display: none; cursor: pointer;"> <input type="hidden" id="3709" name="IDHidden" value="some text"
            <td style="display: none; cursor: pointer;"> <input type="hidden" id="3709" name="IDHidden" value="1/2/2016 1:34:56 AM"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead></table>
```

Comment: How does the rendered HTML looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

Your hidden fields are input fields, `text()` method won't work with that.You should use `val()` method which gives you the input field value.

```
$(function(){

  $('#checkableGrid tr').each(function (i, e) {

     var _tr=$(this);

      _tr.find("td").each(function(i,t) {       
        console.log($(this).text());
      });
      console.log("Will print input values now");

      _tr.find("input[type='hidden']").each(function(a,b) {
         console.log($(this).val());
      });    

 });


 $(document).on("click","#checkableGrid td:not(:first)",function (e) {
       console.log($(this).text());
 });


});
```

Comment: How can I get the data based on row click

Comment: In my answer, i have the click event registered to td where we read the text of td. You can update that to get whatever value you want.